# Understanding Linux CPU usage

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, cpu-usage, top

I'm stuck with profiling a process of mine, named (see `top` output) `xspectra-frameb`.

Its inner structure can be summarized as the following:

- 8 threads are `recv`ing bursts of data from socket connections, mutexing write access to a buffer
- a single thread in charge of data synchronization (program behaves as a kind of data-feed aggregator), mutexing read access to the buffer

Processor is a Xeon with 4 hyper-threading cores. Graph shows all of them as quite idle during my cpu burst, but `top` shows different values (**125.9%**).

Which value should I trust more ?

[image: Top vs Gnome *System Monitor*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`top` counts each core as 100%. You have 8 cores, so 800% is full CPU load.

Let's sum up values from the System Monitor:

> 21.2 + 10.8 + 20.7 + 18.4 + 27.8 + 27.3 + 37.9 + 26.9 = 191%

This roughly equals the `top` score:

> 125.9 + 66.4 + 9.0 + 7.3 + 4.0 + 3.7 + 3.0 + 3.0 + 3.0 + 0.3 + 0.3 + 0.3 = 226.2%

Why the difference? Core loads aren't read simultaneously. Each core is queried one by one, plus `top` and System Monitor don't do it simultaneously. That's why results will differ.

You may want to use `htop` which is less confusing and shows core loads separately.